# Animation when hovering in UserControl

Tags: c#

I would like to make a UserControl that has 2 Background and BGHover properties. And when you hover the cursor on the UserControl, the Background control changes to BGHover (most likely with the help of ColorAnimation) and when MouseLeave Background changes back to the one that was.

```
SolidColorBrush bgColor = (SolidColorBrush)Background;
        this.MouseEnter += delegate (object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
            bgColor = (SolidColorBrush)Background;
            DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(0, myBtn.Width, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
            indicatorBtn.BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, anim);
            ColorAnimation animC = new ColorAnimation(BGHover, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
            myBtn.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animC);
        };
        this.MouseLeave += delegate (object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
            DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(myBtn.Width, 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
            indicatorBtn.BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, anim);
            ColorAnimation animC = new ColorAnimation(BGHover, Color.FromArgb(bgColor.Color.A, bgColor.Color.R, bgColor.Color.G, bgColor.Color.B), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
            myBtn.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animC);
        };
```

With the hover, I change the Background to the BGHover color. But with MouseLeave the color remains the same as BGHover.

Comment: Where is the code example demonstrating what you've tried?

Comment: Hi Павел, it would make sense for you to start by building your first "hello world" user control. Then attempt to customize yourself. Once you run into a well defined problem ask a new question.

Comment: N-ate 
I'm sorry, but I'll figure it out for myself and how to teach. At me now a question only why bgColor varies on BGHover and as it to bypass.

Comment: Why can not you help me? You do not understand the question or you are lazy!