# Background Color Changes

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

```
SolidColorBrush bgColor;

public ModernBTN() {
  InitializeComponent();
  this.Loaded += delegate (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    bgColor = (SolidColorBrush)Background;
    MouseEnter += EnterAnim;
    MouseLeave += LeaveAnim;
  };
}

private void EnterAnim(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(0, myBtn.Width, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
  indicatorBtn.BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, anim);
  ColorAnimation animC = new ColorAnimation(BGHover, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
  myBtn.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animC);
}

private void LeaveAnim(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {          
  DoubleAnimation anim = new DoubleAnimation(myBtn.Width, 0, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
  indicatorBtn.BeginAnimation(WidthProperty, anim);
  ColorAnimation animC = new ColorAnimation(Color.FromArgb(bgColor.Color.A, bgColor.Color.R, bgColor.Color.G, bgColor.Color.B), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
  myBtn.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animC);
}
```

Please tell me why bgColor changes to BGHover color if I put bgColor values ​​only in this.Loaded and = (SolidColorBrush) Background.

ModernBtn.xaml xaml code of my button

```
<UserControl x:Class="ModernButton.ModernBTN"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ModernButton"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="200" Name="myBtn" Background = '#FF282829'>
<Grid Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Name="mainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=BtnText}" FontSize="24" Foreground="#FFC7BBBB" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Name="txtBtn" Padding="{Binding ElementName=myBtn, Path=TextPadding}"></TextBlock>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Lime" Height="5" Name="indicatorBtn" Width="0"></Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

Comment: How did you set `myBtn.Background` at the beginning? Is it set to `bgColor`?

Comment: Just found out that you asked almost exactly [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52451109/animation-when-hovering-in-usercontrol) a few hours ago already. Please try to add additional content to the existing question instead of opening a new one.

Comment: I set MainWindow.xaml to UserControl with the value Background = "# FF282829" and BGHover = "Silver". When hovering on the UserControl Background, it changes to Silver. But with MouseLeave it remains Silver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> bgColor = (SolidColorBrush)Background;

Because `SolidColorBrush` is a reference type, `bgColor` and `Background` will reference the same object after the above line. So, when changes are made to `Background` (as you do with the animation), this changes will be reflected in `bgColor`.

An easy way to solve this may be to change`bgColor` to type `Color`:

```
Color bgColor;

public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   this.Loaded += delegate (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        bgColor = ((SolidColorBrush)Background).Color;
        MouseEnter += EnterAnim;
        MouseLeave += LeaveAnim;
   };
}

private void EnterAnim(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ColorAnimation animC = new ColorAnimation(BGHover, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
    myBtn.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animC);
}

private void LeaveAnim(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ColorAnimation animC = new ColorAnimation(bgColor, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200));
    myBtn.Background.BeginAnimation(SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty, animC);
}
```